# Titanic Dataset - Feature Engineering - Ticket feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, correlation, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I am currently building my first machine learning model using the titanic dataset.
After the data exploration, I decided to focus my attention on the 'Ticket' feature.
One thing I have noticed about this feature is that it is not unique per each passenger; this had led me to believe that other features can be extracted from this variable:

- Is_Group -> to indicate if the ticket represents a group booking
- Group_Size -> the number of passengers in each group.

```
# save the tickets that appear more than once (i.e. group tickets)
_ = (data.Ticket.value_counts()>1).to_dict()
ls = []
for key in _:
    if _[key]==True:
        ls.append(key)
#extract the feature
data['Is_Group'] = data['Ticket'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in(ls) else 0)

# create another dict containing the number of counts per each ticket
group_size = (data.Ticket.value_counts()).to_dict()
# extract the feature from the mapping
data['Group_Size'] = data['Ticket'].map(group_size).fillna(0)
```

The reason I am doing this is because I wanted to explore the nature of the relationship between the extracted features from Ticket and the target Survived (and later decide how to deal with outliers in the SibSp and Parch feature):

```
data.groupby(['Is_Group','Group_Size'])['Survived'].describe()
```

Link to df: [image]

From the above table, I can see that group size 2/3 has almost a 60% and 70% chance of survival. Now, this led me to think that there is a correlation (or at least some sort of relationship between group size and Survived). Therefore, I decided to create a correlation matrix to make sure that is the case.

link to df: [image]

As I expected there is a correlation between Is_Group and Group_Size (as they have been extracted from the same feature) but there is **no correlation** between these extracted features and Survived. Hence my, confusion. 
I thought given the high mean values of Survived for Group_Size (2,3) there was a relationship but clearly, I am getting something wrong here.

Can anyone help clear this doubt of mine?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe the same ticket number is for the family members? And it will be enough to use SibSp and Parch?

Answer (score 2):

The correlation coefficient being close to zero indicates that there is no strong *linear* relationship, not that there is no relationship at all. From your table it is evident that if there is an association between group size and survival, it is more complex than a simple linear relation.

Also keep in mind that you are ignoring the strong confounders sex, age and class here. For example, a group size of three may indicate an adult couple from the upper class with one child, with the woman and child likely surviving, but not the man. This would explain the observed survival rate of about 2/3 for that group size.